# Preferred way to include Advanced Custom Fields in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, advanced-custom-fields

So I am building a plugin for a site that is already using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF). I wonder what would be the best way to include ACF in my plugin? The site is already using ACF, so is it possible to include ACF from the plugin directory or should I include ACF again?

Comment: Here's one method which may be useful http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

Comment: thx man! Really appreciated, il take a look.

Comment: You have two options: 1) Included it in your plugin or theme 2) Make it a requirement for your plugin to work. The first option is generally used by premium themes where it configures all the fields. The second is done by plugins that are adding a new field type that anybody else could add themselves to their configuration.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started/including-acf-in-a-plugin-theme/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ACF (or any other plugin) is active on the site you do not need to include its files as they are all being included in the wordpress initialization process. The only tricky part is that you don't know the order in which files are included and yours might be included before the ACF files are included, therefor you should probably wait for the `init` action or even later action before using it.

Side note: ACF provides GUI for custom fields, but if you just need to use the data it is better not to rely on its API and query using the `get_post_meta` API. This will result in better software modularization and hopefully a more maintainable site.

Comment: It is possible to disable the GUI for the admin of editing the fields while still enabling the GUI on the post edit pages. `define( 'ACF_LITE' , true );`

Comment: I did the following to make sure it only loads if AFC is not already included 'if( !class_exists('Acf') )'

Comment: @StenW, that is exactly the point of my sidenote, if tomorrow ACF on that site will be replaced by another plugin your code will fail with no reason at all. Your code should rely as little as possible o the existence of another plugin. If AFC was disabled it is not your place to force its inclusion.

Comment: I get your point, smart call!

Comment: @MarkKaplun any suggestions on which action to use?

Comment: no, actually `init` is just to play safe, anything after 'plugins_loaded' should be fine, but it all depends on what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: Read up on it and I think 'plugins_loaded' is good for this specific case. all I want to do it check if ACF is loaded and if not load, ACF.

Answer (score 3):

**This information has been updated!**

Please see ACF's website:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/including-acf-in-a-plugin-theme/

Well you would just check by if ACF class exists `if( !class_exists('acf') )` to check if a user has ACF installed already and if not then, fall-back on your version of ACF you would included along with your plugin or theme, setting `ACF_LITE` to "not" show ACF menu to the user...

But if a user decides to install ACF themselves, it will override your version included with you plugin or theme as expected :).

```
    // Optionally you can use below to check by plugin location:
    // if((is_plugin_active('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php'))|| (is_plugin_active('advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php'))):
        

        // Check if ACF Classes exists: 
        if(!class_exists('acf_pro') || !class_exists('acf')):
            
            // Define path and URL to the ACF plugin.
            define( 'MY_ACF_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/acf/' );
            define( 'MY_ACF_URL', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/acf/' );
            
            // Include the ACF plugin.
            include_once( MY_ACF_PATH . 'acf.php' );
            
            // Customize the url setting to fix incorrect asset URLs.
            add_filter('acf/settings/url', 'my_acf_settings_url');
            function my_acf_settings_url( $url ) {
                return MY_ACF_URL;
            }
            
            // (Optional) Hide the ACF admin menu item.
            add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', 'my_acf_settings_show_admin');
            function my_acf_settings_show_admin( $show_admin ) {
                return false;
            }
            
            
       endif;
```

Also. After you have made your fields and field group with ACF, export them to PHP using ACF's export feature. Then include that exported PHP into you plugin/theme.

ACF is so powerful. And I am grateful for Elliott generosity of allowing us to even use PRO into making our plugins!

Comment: The last edition does not make sense, the condition will always be met. I think it should be `if(!class_exists('acf_pro') && !class_exists('acf'))`.

Comment: Ditto I think this should be when the plugins are not activated, not when they are.

Answer (score 1):

Am I doing it wrong, or do others find this clunky: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started/including-acf-in-a-plugin-theme/

So in order to include ACF in my plugin and hide ACF from users in the WP admin, I need to:

- Set up a local site with ACF
- Export the custom fields to PHP
- Import the custom fields PHP into my plugin

Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you want ACF to be part of your plugin, In other words; If you do not want the user of your plugin to haveing to activate their own version of ACF then you have to include it t your plugin the way you explain. Correct.

Comment: Well you would just make sure to check for it's function ```if( !class_exists('acf_pro') )``` to check if a user has ACF PRO installed and if not, fall back on your version of ACF you have included along with the plugin or theme, setting ACF_LITE to not show ACF to the user...But if a user decides to install ACF themselves, it will override your version included with you plugin or theme. This is a better function: ```if((is_plugin_active('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php')) || ( class_exists('acf_pro') ) || ( class_exists('acf') ) || (is_plugin_active('advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php'))):```

Comment: This check: ```if((is_plugin_active('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php')) || ( class_exists('acf_pro') ) || ( class_exists('acf') ) || (is_plugin_active('advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php'))):``` look for it ACF PRO or ACF is installed and active.